# VBA Excel sheets copied in wrong order

Tags: excel, vba

Good morning,

I am using the following code:

```
 Sub CABsheet()

 Dim i As Long
 Dim xNumber As Long
 Dim xName As String
 Dim ws As Worksheet

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 Set ws = Sheets("CAB1")
 xNumber = Sheets("NIM & BADGER").Range("R27").Value

 For i = 1 To Number
 ws.Copy After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ws.Index + i - 1)
 ActiveSheet.Name = "CAB" & i + 1
 Next

 ws.Activate

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 End Sub
```

but I am getting an error saying, that the sheet under this name already exists.

[image]

when I use a bit changed code like this:

```
 Sub CABsheet()

 Dim i As Long
 Dim xNumber As Long
 Dim xName As String
 Dim ws As Worksheet

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 Set ws = Sheets("CAB1")
 xNumber = Sheets("NIM & BADGER").Range("R27").Value

 For i = 2 To Number
 ws.Copy After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ws.Index + (i - 2))
 ActiveSheet.Name = "CAB" & (i + 1) + 2
 Next

 ws.Activate

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 End Sub
```

then an error is gone, and everything seems to be alright but...

[image]

... i am getting numeration from CAB5 onwards instead of CAB 2

If I change a bit of my code again...

```
 For i = 2 To xNumber
 ws.Copy After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ws.Index + (i - 1))
 ActiveSheet.Name = "CAB" & i + 2
 Next
```

[image]

then order is wrong.

The tabs are from CAB4 onwards.

I need them from CAB2 onwards. 
I can't remove +2 because the debugger shows me an error, that the name already been taken.

What can I fix in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your very first code example you

```
Dim xNumber As Long
```

you set a value for it

```
xNumber = Sheets("NIM & BADGER").Range("R27").Value
```

and then you use the variable `Number` instead of `xNumber` in your loop:

```
For i = 2 To Number
```

The variable `Number` is not declared nor initialized with a value and therefore it is `0`.

So this cannot work. Make sure you use `Option Explicit` so you get notified if you use a worng variable name that was not declared.

---

I also recommend not to use `ActiveSheet`

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CABsheet()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CAB1")

    Dim xNumber As Long
    xNumber = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NIM & BADGER").Range("R27").Value

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To xNumber
       ws.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ws.Index + i - 1)
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ws.Index + i).Name = "CAB" & i + 1
    Next

    ws.Activate

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Before running the code:
[image]

After running the code:
[image]

---

You could also built in a test if the worksheet already exists and ask the user if it should be deleted:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CABsheet()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CAB1")

    Dim xNumber As Long
    xNumber = 10

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To xNumber
        ws.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ws.Index + i - 1)
        If WorksheetExists("CAB" & i + 1) Then
            If MsgBox("Worksheet '" & "CAB" & i + 1 & "' already exists. Do you want to delete it?", vbExclamation + vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CAB" & i + 1).Delete
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ws.Index + i).Name = "CAB" & i + 1
            End If
        Else
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ws.Index + i).Name = "CAB" & i + 1
        End If
    Next

    ws.Activate

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Public Function WorksheetExists(ByVal WorksheetName As String, Optional ByVal InWorkbook As Workbook) As Boolean
    If InWorkbook Is Nothing Then
        Set InWorkbook = ThisWorkbook
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = InWorkbook.Worksheets(WorksheetName)
    On Error GoTo 0

    WorksheetExists = Not ws Is Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: It doesn't solve my issue. I have made a mistake in rewriting this code. It was correct in my original one. The problem might lie somewhere in the loop range I think because the code picks up the very first sheet, which shouldn't do.

Comment: @MariuszKrukar check my edited code again. I tested it and it worked as expected.

Comment: Yes I did, the same :(
Debugger:
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ws.Index + i).Name = "CAB" & i + 1

Comment: Then you probably have some hidden sheet named `CAB2` check it. I tested with a brand new workbook and it definitely works.

Comment: I guess so! Let me check

Comment: Yes, you was right, there was the CAB3 sheet hidden without the reason. Thank you very much for your hint!

Comment: @MariuszKrukar You can built in a test for better usability. Check my edited answer.